# Get user id without using parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have few users they want to create SSRS reports. Based on their user id, data should be driven from the table associated to their user id. Dataset should be smart enough to handle / identify user id without passing user id as a parameter. How do i handle this scenario?

I tried this....I have created userid parameter and passed as a parameter to where condition but my manager doesn't want this way. Because there is a possibility if user creates a report without passing user id, user can see all rows, which is wrong. Only data associated to that user should be able to see.

Comment: who not make the userid internal and pass it to the dataset query from your login rather than making it an interactive parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the user ID with this function in the custom code section:

```
Public Function UserName() As String
    Return Report.User!UserID
End Function
```

and call it from everywhere with:

```
=Code.UserName
```